# Math environment misjudged

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Command `\ifmmode` misjudged in math environment of package `amsmath`. An mwe is like

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  \ifmmode123\else456\fi
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

In math eqvironment, it should have produced `123` in `gather` environment. But the outcome is just the opposite. Similar cases appear in `align`, `eqarray` and so on. But in `equation`, it produces the right outcome. Is this a bug? Or how to fix it? Thansks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `\protect` the invocation of `\ifmmode`.  David's comment provides more info on the "why".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  \protect\ifmmode abc\else def\fi
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: no not the multi-pass (you will see the same in array, which is one pass) it is the lookahead for `\multicolumn` or `\hline` that happens before the cell (and so math mode) starts.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle I will edit out that comment.